# able to get uuid from Ubuntu server but not uuid on a mac OSX

Tags: macos

here is a resource that helped me get the product UUID for our ubuntu servers, I want to give it proper credit:

http://www.outflux.net/blog/archives/2012/02/10/kvm-and-product_uuid/comment-page-1/#comment-1324

I do have a question though, how would you get the same thing from a Mac or MacBook?  Mac is linux based but this same command does not work.

Comment: Mac OS X is *not* "linux based".

Comment: OK, I assumed so because of the linux commands I was executing in terminal.  In any case, I'm pleased to answer my own question (below)

Answer (score 0):

This command works for me on an OSX system!  Just wanted to share it:

```
system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | awk '/Hardware UUID:/ {print $NF}'
```